# Serverless Dashboard: Set API Gateway Log Retention

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I’m using the Serverless Dashboard to monitor my API Gateway and Lambda. I’m trying to edit the log retention days of API Gateway’s log group programmatically. However, Serverless (maybe) doesn’t support retention days on API Gateway. Is there any way I can automate that? Thank you in advance.

Already asked Serverless forum: https://forum.serverless.com/t/api-gateway-log-retention/9778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless as of now doesn't supports log retention for API Gateway. However there are external plugins/workaround that can be used to the same.

Links below:-

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1918

https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-aws-alias/issues/57